# User-agent mixing iPhone & Googlebot

Tags: iphone, user-agent, googlebot

On my site, I'm seeing this "strange" user-agent:

> Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+U;+CPU+iPhone+OS+4_1+like+Mac+OS+X;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/532.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0.5+Mobile/8B117+Safari/6531.22.7+(compatible;+Googlebot-Mobile/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Do you know if it is an iPhone or the Google Bot?

Answer (score 1):

It's **Googlebot-Mobile**!

A quick Google search and I got these links. None of which are very good, but together you can sort of get a grasp of what's happening:

- http://www.seroundtable.com/iphone-google-bot-12999.html
- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=4bd840488982ed11&hl=en
- http://chrispederick.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=2907